# Different stubs generated by ColdFusion on two different servers

Tags: java, web-services, coldfusion, stubs

We have a dev server and a live server, both running ColdFusion 9.  The ColdFusion versions are the same, the Java versions are the same, the JVM versions are the same.  I am trying to connect to an external web service with coldfusion and on dev it works fine.  On live, I'm getting the error: "Web service operation XXX with parameters {blah blah} cannot be found."  I checked the stubs on both servers, and the live server is generating several MORE stubs than the dev server, and they are all called ArrayOf[XYZ] (where [XYZ] is some object).  On dev, I am able to pass a component with nested components and arrays of components to the external web service and get a response.  On live, I get the error, and I believe it's because on live, it's expecting the arrays to actually be objects.  What would cause this to happen, and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  There was a different version of Apache Axis running on the live server -- a very old 1.2.1  version.  We upgraded live to the 1.4 version that was running on our dev server, and it solved the issue.